# How do i create a table using python code

Tags: python-3.x

I'm struggling with creating a table which will input data in a database using python.

Comment: You're missing all the important details of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Table

go.Table provides a Table object for detailed data viewing

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))])

fig.show()
```